# Notepad++ How can I delete the return before the &

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, carriage-return

I want to remove a new line created right before an &

SAMPLE TEXT:

"Bachelor of Science in Nursing 
& RN"
"Bachelor of Science in Nursing 
& RN"
"Bachelor of Science in Nursing 
& RN"

I want it look like this:
“Bachelor of Science in Nursing & RN”
"Bachelor of Science in Nursing & RN”
"Bachelor of Science in Nursing & RN"

I apologize, I know this should be easy and I tried different \r \n commands, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.
thank you all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ Remove New Line Pattern - Find & Replace Command?](https://superuser.com/questions/1338783/notepad-remove-new-line-pattern-find-replace-command)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

Search string : `\r\n&`
Replace by :  `&` (note the blank at the beginning)
Search Mode : Regular expression
Check `. matches newline`